# Spring security 3.1 Custom filter issue. Problems with anonymous urls exclusion

Tags: java, spring, rest, cookies, spring-security

I'm developing a RESTful api. There are two types of security restrictions on my urls:

- /rest/autenticate (anonymous in order to generate a token and receive the cookie)
- /rest/** (handled by AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter which get the cookie and check it out)

The main idea is to access to /authenticate anonymously in order to get the cookie and access to the other /rest/users /rest/.. with that cookie and check its validity on the custom filter.

This is my http config:

```
<http realm="Protected REST API" pattern="/rest/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless"  entry-point-ref="RestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter ref="AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/authenticate*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</http>
```

I also implemented some classes to do it works:

```
<b:bean id="RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="**.web.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" /> 

<b:bean id="customAuthenticationManager" class="**.web.security.CustomAuthenticationManager"/>

<b:bean id="AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" class="**.web.security.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg type="**.web.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager"></b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <b:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <b:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="**.web.security.RestAccessDeniedHandler">
    <b:property name="accessDeniedUrl" value="403" />
</b:bean>
```

Instead of going to the controller direcly, the doFilter of AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter method intercepts /rest/authenticate.

This is my AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter:

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired 
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired 
    TokenUtilsService tokenUtilsService;

    CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager) {
        this.customAuthenticationManager = customAuthenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Check the cookie calling to customAuthenticationManager.authenticate
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I thought that this filter is only launched when a url is restricted. Maybe is always launched and I have to check if the role is anonymous manually?

The solution will be voted and checked.

Comment: The filter is always executed for all /rest urls.

Comment: so.. what can i do it?

Comment: Check if the request needs to be processed or can simply pass along.

Comment: yes, but in the do filter how can i check if the role is anonymous?

Comment: Well you cannot check anonymous (due to the position in the lifecycle) you can check if the user is authenticated or not. By simply calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()` or you could try to get hold of a `SecurityExpressionOperations` in your filter which you can then ask several things.

Comment: The SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() is not suitable because it always says that is not authenticated obiously. Is there any posibility not to pass through the filter?

Comment: Didn't notice the `stateless` flag in your configuration, indeed then it isn't going to work. Then I would check if the cookie/credentials are there if they are you can proceed if not check if the URL is '/rest/authenticate' if so authenticate.

Comment: So, anyone of the <intercept-url> works if you have a custom Processing filter? If you implements the filter you have to intercept the url and check the credentials manually?

Comment: You can use an explicitly configured `filter-chain`, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/security-filter-chain.html

Comment: You able to find a solution for this? I need to do something similar